# Update SeekBar at particular position within a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an application for downloading songs. In my application, there is a `RecyclerView` with a list of songs and with every song there is a `SeekBar` below that shows the download progress. When I hit the download button, it works fine but it updates the wrong `SeekBar`. I want to update a particular `SeekBar` at a particular position. Here is my adapter for the `RecyclerView`:

```
@Override
    public SongListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        itemViewLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.song_list_single_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(itemViewLayout);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SongListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        mSongListModel = mSongListArray.get(position);
        holder.downloadLink.setText(mSongListModel.getDownloadLink());
        holder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DownloadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSongListArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            System.out.println("Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was " + grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
            //downloadStreamingAudio();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView downloadLink;
        private SeekBar downloadProgress;
        private TextView downloadButton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            downloadLink = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.downloadLink);
            downloadButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
            downloadProgress = (SeekBar) itemViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgress);
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        Uri uri;
        String timeStamp;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downlaoding Audio...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AppDownloads/");

                    timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                    System.out.println("Time Stamp::----" + timeStamp);

                    try {
                        if (dir.exists() == false) {
                            dir.mkdirs();
                        }

                        RootFile = new File(dir, timeStamp + ".mp3");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                int count;

                System.out.println("DownloadUrl::::----"+mSongListArray.get(Integer.parseInt(params[0])).getDownloadLink());
                URL url = new URL(mSongListArray.get(Integer.parseInt(params[0])).getDownloadLink());
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

                // downlod the file
                input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                output = new FileOutputStream(RootFile);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    //publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
                    updateDownloadProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e)

            {

                Log.d("Error....", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())

                pDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(c, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (c.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                System.out.println("Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                System.out.println("Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) c, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void updateDownloadProgress(int progress) {
        holder.downloadProgress.setProgress(progress);

    }
```

Here is my layout file for the `RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/downloadLink"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="DOWNLOAD"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="PLAY"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/downloadProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: and which seekbar is updating?

Comment: Random....but mostly last one

Comment: maybe the problem is in updateDownloadProgress..which you update the progress bar of holder and not of a specific item, try some way to update particular item in holder..

Comment: I don't think so because when i download this without using RecyclerView it works fine.

Comment: wait..each song has its own progress bar..when you want to download the songs..do they download all together and you just want the progress bar of each individual song to show the right progress status ?

Comment: I have added my layout file for single item...each item has its own download button

Comment: You can use `notifyitemchanged` to update particular item at particular index.

Comment: where can i use notifyitemchanged ?

Comment: Since `onCreateViewHolder` is called for each row of `RecyclerView`, `holder` variable refer to the last `ViewHolder`.

Comment: Yes i noticed...but how can i maintain positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is tightly-coupled. I recommend you to split program into 3 peaces.
And Call `notifyItemChanged` at `onProgressUpdated`

Below code is examples.

RecyclerView.Adapter like this:

```
public class SongListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...

    private final Listener mListener;
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> progressMap = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    interface Listener {
        void onClickDownload(int position, SongListModel songListModel);
    }

    public SongListAdapter(Listener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SongListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ...
        int progress = progressMap.containsKey(position) ? progressMap.get(position) : 0;
        holder.downloadProgress.setProgress(progress);
        holder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SongListModel songListModel = mSongListArray.get(position);
                mListener.onClickDownload(position, songListModel);
            }
        });
    }
    ...

    public void setProgress(int position, int progress) {
        progressMap.put(position, progress);
    }
    ...
}
```

DownloadFileAsync like this:

```
public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ...
    private final Callback mCallback;
    private final int mPosition;
    private final SongListModel mSongListModel;

    interface Callback {
        void onDownloadStarting();
        void onProgressUpdated(int progress, int position, SongListModel songListModel);
        void onDownloadCompleted();
    }

    public DownloadFileAsync(Callback callback, int position, SongListModel songListModel) {
        mCallback = callback;
        mPosition = position;
        mSongListModel = songListModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mCallback.onDownloadStarting();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            ...
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                ...
                mCallback.onProgressUpdated((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile), mPosition, mSongListModel);
                ...
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ...
        }
        return null;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        mCallback.onDownloadCompleted(s);
    }
}
```

Activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SongListAdapter.Listener, DownloadFileAsync.Callback {
    ...

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SongListAdapter mAdapter;
    private DownloadFileAsync mDownloadFileAsync;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(...);
        mAdapter = new SongListAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickDownload(int position, SongListModel songListModel) {
        if (mDownloadFileAsync != null) {
            //TODO currentry downloading. Insert error handing.
            return;
        }

        mDownloadFileAsync = new DownloadFileAsync(this, position, songListModel);
        mDownloadFileAsync.execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDownloadStarting() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downlaoding Audio...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdated(int progress, int position, SongListModel songListModel) {
        mAdapter.setProgress(position, progress);

        SongListAdapter.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        if (holder != null) {
            holder.downloadProgress.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadCompleted(String s) {
        mDownloadFileAsync = null;
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // If you want to stop downloading when activity is closing, call cancel method.
        if (mDownloadFileAsync != null) {
            mDownloadFileAsync.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I updated my answer. `MainActivity.onProgressUpdated` and etc was updated. Please see diffs http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39165865/revisions  @AbhayBohra

Answer (score 0):

holder = new ViewHolder(itemViewLayout);

You assign the last created holder as the holder you are updating the progress. do not use a global variable as the holder, instead:

Make the Holder onBindViewHolder() final.

Your AsyncTask should also get a reference to this holder. Maybe create a Holder variable inside the AsyncTask, and set that holder to the one that was binded onBindViewHolder().

Your execute code should look something like this.

```
DownloadFileAsync task = new DownloadFileAsync(String.valueOf(position));
task.setHolder(holder);
task.execute();
```

Good luck.