# control progress bar inside item of recycleView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I have a `recycleView`, each item in `recycleView` have one `progressbar` and a button, how I can click a `Button` and `progressbar` load.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your adapter code here?

Comment: what you done in code. add code here

Comment: Check out this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39165865/3789993

Comment: what have you done to achieve this?

Comment: Have you resolved this? I want to do the same thing, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume, you know the length of the audio message.
In your method:

```
     @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder vholder, int position) {
                AudioMessage holder =  vholder;
```

you should register the button onClick listener.

Something like this:

```
       //indicate length here.
       mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
       //We'll dynamically change i to show progress,
       int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ i+ millisUntilFinished);
            i++;
            mProgressBar.setProgress((int)i*100/(5000/1000));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        //Do what you want 
            i++;
            mProgressBar.setProgress(100);
        }
    };
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        int i=0;
    holder.mProgressBar.setProgress(i);
    mCountDownTimer.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your click logic to the `Adapter`, specifically, in your `onBindViewHolder` method like this -

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             loadProgress();//method that starts your Progress Bar
        }
    });

}
```